# Storing game data for 2D game like Star Ocean Second Story and Legend of Mana

Tags: ios, data-structures, opengl-es

I'm trying to go for a 2D game like Legend of Mana and Star Ocean Second Story rather than tile based 2D games.

### OVERVIEW

Currently, the way I'm going about building my game is like so:

I have geometry files and texture files. Geometry files store width, height, XY position, Texture ID number to use and texture name to use.

The way I'm trying to do is:

I will have a scene manager object that loads "scene" objects. Each scene object stores a list of all geometry objects in that scene as well as texture and sound objects (to be implemented).

Each scene is rendered using vertex array whereby the scene manager object would call a method like get scene vertices by scene name which returns a pointer to an array of GLFloats (GLfloat *) and this pointer to GLfloat gets used in OpenGL's glVertexPointer() function.

When I want to update each character's position (like the hero for example), my aim is to use the "hero" game objects in the current scene and call a function like:

```
Hero.Move(newXPosition, newYPosition);
```

which will actually alter the hero geometry object's vertex data. So it will do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    vertexList[i] = vertexList[i] + newXPosition;
    vertexList[i+1] = vertexList[i+1] + newYPosition;
    ...
}
```

This way, when I go to render the scene in the render frame, it will render the entire scene again with the updated vertex coordinates.

Each object in the game will just be a quadrilateral with a texture mapped to it.

### THE PROBLEM

I'm using Objective C for my programming and OpenGL. This is for iOS platform.

I have been successful thus far using this method to render 1 object.

The problem I have is I'm using a NSMutableDictionary which is a data structure that uses key-value pair to store geometry instance objects in the scene object class. Dictionaries in Objective C doesn't retrieve data in the same order every time the code is run. It retrieves then in random order.

Becausing of this, I am having trouble combining all the vertex array data from each geometry object in the scene object and passing out 1 single vertex pointer to GLfloats.

Each geometry object stores it's own array of 8 vertex values (4 pairs of X,Y coordinate value). I would like each geometry object to manage it's own vertices (so I can use Move, Rotate like mentioned earlier) and at the same time, I would like my scene object to be able to output a single pointer reference to all vertices data of all geometry objects in the current scene for using in OpenGL's glVertexArray() function.

I am trying to avoid calling OpenGL's glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4) multiple times. Like draw hero, draw map, draw AI agents, draw BG objects. That would not be very efficient. Minimizing the amount of GL draw calls as much as possible (to 1 draw call preferably), especially on limited hardware like the iPhone is what was suggested when I was reading about OpenGL game development.

### SUGGESTIONS?

What is the best practice way of going about doing what I'm trying to do?

Should I use a SQL database to store my game data like geometry vertices data and load JUST 1 scene into iPhone memory from the sql database file on iPhone's disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a a list of lists to keep track of draw layer and order, and use the dictionary solely for fast lookup.

Answer (score 0):

What I don't understand is why you don't use Cocos2D, that happens to be built on the scene manager paradigm. Think of all the development time you will save...

I have worked in a company that did wonderful games. It eventually died because they kept putting out buggy games, due to the lack of development time for debugging. They did however find time to create a graphics rendering engine.

I thought, and still think, they had wrong priorities. It seems to me you are doing the same mistake: are you trying to make an iOS game, or are you trying to learn how to do a 2D gaming engine for iOS?

Note: Cocos2D is Open Source, you can therefore read it, now that you have thought about the process to create such an engine.

Comment: Well, time isn't a constraint for me. I want to learn to development games from the ground up and get a deeper understanding of how everything fits together. Yes game engine saves time, I've done a bit of Actionscript games programming before and it does make it a lot easier. Short answer: both :P Thanks for the quick reply nonetheless.

Comment: Then if it is for learning enjoyment, I can't but wish you luck, you are a true geek!